# How to DISABLE error.html load in Spring Boot REST with Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am receiving this error message in the browser every time I access an invalid endpoint or some managed error happens inside de code, in my Spring Boot Application:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/error.html]")
```

It means that my Spring Boot is overriding it's white label error messages and tries do show me the error with a Thymeleaf error template page.

I have found many tutorials on the web on how to use this `template/error.html` scheme, but haven't found any that shows me HOW TO NOT USE Thymeleaf for managing my error responses.

I want to use Thymeleaf in my REST Server only as a template processor for e-mail messages my server sends.

**Does anyone knows how to configure Spring Boot to use it's default white label error messages and forget about Thymeleaf?**

I tried to use `server.error.whitelabel.enabled = true` but did not worked.

My `applications.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.context-path         = /apli
server.port                         = 8080
server.use-forward-headers          = true
server.error.whitelabel.enabled     = true
management.endpoint.restart.enabled = true

spring.mvc.locale                       = pt-BR
spring.mvc.locale-resolver              = fixed

spring.messages.encoding                = UTF-8
spring.messages.basename                = i18n/messages

logging.level.org.springframework.web       = warn
logging.level.org.hibernate                 = info
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL             = warn
logging.level.org.hibernate.type            = info
logging.level.org.hibernate.jpa.internal    = warn
logging.level.org.hibernate.hql.internal    = warn

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto                      = update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl                            = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql         = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments   = true
spring.jpa.show-sql                                = false

spring.mail.host                                   = smtp.********
spring.mail.port                                   = 25
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout = 10000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout           = 10000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout      = 10000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable   = false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required = false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.debug             = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth              = true
spring.mail.username = *****
spring.mail.password = *****

spring.jackson.mapper.default-view-inclusion     = true
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans = false

spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location = true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix                  = classpath:templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix                  = .html
spring.thymeleaf.mode                    = HTML
spring.thymeleaf.encoding                = UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type    = text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache                   = false

spring.flyway.enabled                 = true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate     = true
spring.flyway.baseline-version        = 1
spring.flyway.placeholder-replacement = false
spring.flyway.validate-on-migrate     = false
spring.flyway.out-of-order            = true
```

Comment: What annotatiins do you use on your controllers? Since you are using Thymeleaf only for mail rendering, try to use “@RestController” instead “@Controller” on you controller class level.

Comment: It's already RestController in all Rest Classes I use. Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the white label error page entirely, by setting the `server.error.whitelabel.enabled` property to `false` in your `application.properties`:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```